# Get Empty Collection instead of null when mapping with Mapster

Tags: c#, .net, mapster

We have an huge data driven application that involves multiple systems therefore a lot of mapping is needed. 
Due to performance issues we are gonna migrate from AutoMapper to Mapster.

Everything's good so far with Mapster but when mapping the `Collections` Mapster returns `null` value instead of empty `Collection`.

Automapper used to return Empty Collections by default but I am unable to figure out how to do that in Mapster.

I have tried doing the following but it does not work

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.ForDestinationType<ICollection>().IgnoreNullValues(true);

TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.ForType(typeof(ICollection), typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
                        .IgnoreNullValues(true);

TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.ForType(typeof(ObservableCollection<>), typeof(ICollection))
                        .IgnoreNullValues(true);
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working thanks to Mapster team. Posting it here in case anyone else needs it

You can either configure it explicitly by:

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default
    .AddDestinationTransform((IReadOnlyList<ChildDto> list) => list ?? new List<ChildDto>());
```

Mapster has also added generic support for `AddDestinationTransform`

```
config.Default.AddDestinationTransform(DestinationTransform.EmptyCollectionIfNull);
```

This worked for me.